# how to insert leaders with periods around dot?

Tags: commands

(This is not about org-mode.)
Assume point is between "left" and "right" below
    `left       right`
Is there a command that will change that to, for example,
    `left . . . right`
and leaves point at the same position?  There should be a minimum of left-space spaces before the first ., dots should be on columns evenly divisible by column-spacing (first column is number 1),  there should be a minimum of right-space spaces after the last dot, and char-to-use is normally a period but can be set to, for example, "_" if wanted.

Comment: Is this about Org mode? If so, please add tag `org-mode`.

Comment: Hi Mark! When you say `dot is between "left" and "right"`, does dot mean the cursor position? In Emacs, the position of the cursor is called `point`. If that's not what you mean, can you clarify for us please?

Comment: @Tyler, thanks, I corrected the question.